# Spring boot application custom validation annotation doesn't fire

Tags: spring-boot, validation, annotations

I want to have custom validation annotation in my spring boot application. I've done everything same as it is shown in examples, but it doesn't fire. What I'm missing? Here is code

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ContactNumberValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ContactNumberConstraint {
    String message() default "Invalid phone number";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

here is validator class

```
public class ContactNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ContactNumberConstraint, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ContactNumberConstraint contactNumber) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String contactField, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        System.out.println("Validating....");

        return contactField != null && contactField.matches("[0-9]+")
                && (contactField.length() > 8) && (contactField.length() < 14);
    }

}
```

and here is controller method

```
@GetMapping("doSomething")
public void doSomething(@ContactNumberConstraint String phone) {
    System.out.println("Do something " + phone);
}
```

Also I added this dependency but I am not sure if it is needed.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some extra things you need to do to use a ConstraintValidator for request arguments:

- Add `@Validated` in your controller class
- Add a MethodValidationPostProcessor bean in a configuration class:

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class SpringConfiguration {

      @Bean
      public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
          return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just added @validated and it started working

Comment: Wish I could give you more than one upvote ^^"